# javascript case-insensitive replace method?

Tags: javascript, case-insensitive, replaceall

is there a way to `replace` a word with another within a page but case-insensitive so that it replaces every word, but also keeps the origianl case of the word it has just replaced? I am currently using this method of which is case-sensitive.

```
document.body.innerHTML = document.body.innerHTML.replace(/hello/g, 'hi');
```

Comment: +1 for this complication: `but also keeps the origianl case of the word it has just replaced`

Comment: You have to use a custom replace callback function that can examine what is being replaced in order to adjust the case of the text to replace it with accordingly.

Comment: If you just wanted to replace `Hello` with `Hi` and `hello` with `hi`, you could do `.replace(/(h|H)ello/g, '$1i')`. But of course that's not a general solution.

Comment: This doesn't make a lot of sense when the words are of different length (just like your example, but probably more-so when the example is reversed)

Comment: Proof of concept for replace using a callback function: http://jsfiddle.net/wolfemm/8e6At/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

add an i after g ... /hello/gi means greedy, case insensitive..
ahh missed the keeps the case part...that gets a bit more complicated..

```
var matches1 = document.getElementById('test').innerHTML.match(/hello/g);
var matches2 = document.getElementById('test').innerHTML.match(/Hello/g);
for(var i=0;i<matches1.length;i++){
  document.getElementById('test').innerHTML =  document.getElementById('test').innerHTML.replace(matches1[i], 'hi');
}
for(var i=0;i<matches2.length;i++){
   document.getElementById('test').innerHTML =  document.getElementById('test').innerHTML.replace(matches2[i], 'Hi');
}
```

Haven't tested it but that should work..

EDIT: /\shello\s/ didn't work with \s's here's a fiddle.. http://jsfiddle.net/w44u6/

EDIT2: Give @Felix Kling a cookie!

```
document.getElementById('test').innerHTML = document.getElementById('test').innerHTML.replace(/hello/g, 'hi').replace(/Hello/g, 'Hi');
```

works as well and is much shorter! example in the same fiddle!

Comment: `but also keeps the origianl case of the word it has just replaced`

Comment: Why the loops instead of `document.body.innerHTML = document.body.innerHTML.replace(/\shello\s/g, 'hi').replace(/\sHello\s/g, 'Hi');` ?

Comment: @Felix - yup, much better solution!